# Not sure why this isn't submitting to my action page? Page just refreshes on submit

Tags: html

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"
<form action="RegnDisplay.php" method="post" class="registration_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form </legend>

    <p>Personal Information </p>

    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Name :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
    </div>
        <p>Security Information </p>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />
    </div>  
       <div class="elements">
          <label for="Password">Confirm Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password_Confirm" name="Password_Confirm" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a basic form, trying to post user submitted values to a processing page, however my page is just blinking and not performing the action. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: nvm i found it. forgot to close my css link. ty!

Answer (score 1):

On line 3:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"
```

Should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
```